# how to send mail from glassfish server?

Tags: java, email, glassfish

How to write a mail application with java mail API that run all time at glassfish server and search a specific time in the database and send mail at that time. i have web application written in JSF that need to send mail at specific time given in database.

Comment: This is not JSF related, just web application. Also, you can send emails using [Java Mail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html), and configure jobs using a scheduler library like [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)

Comment: Check these links: [JavaMail API – Sending Email Via Gmail SMTP Example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/) and [Quartz Scheduler Example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/quartz-scheduler-example/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For gmail, use below code

```
import org.apache.commons.mail.*;

public class GmailEmailWorking {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myEmailId = "xyz@gmail.com";
        String myPassword = "password";
        String senderId = "xyz@yahoo.com";
        try {
            MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
            email.setSmtpPort(587);
            email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(myEmailId, myPassword));
            email.setDebug(true);
            email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
            email.setFrom(myEmailId);
            email.setSubject("Hi");
            email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)\n\nPlease check attachements that I have sent.\n\nThanks,\nFahim");
            email.addTo(senderId);
            email.setTLS(true);

            EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
            attachment.setPath("/Users/fahadparkar/Desktop/Fahim/tables.xlsx");
            attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
            attachment.setDescription("Excel");
            attachment.setName("tables.xlsx");
            email.attach(attachment);

            email.send();
            System.out.println("Mail sent!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception :: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Below are list of jar files you will need

- [commons-email-1.2.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommonsemail12jar.htm)
- [activation.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadactivationjar.htm)
- [mail.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/m/Downloadmailjar.htm)

***To send from other server, you will need to do changes at below line***

```
email.setSmtpPort(587);
email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
```

Comment: Thanks Fahim Parkar. its really helpful.